# How to insert object in between the array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I want to insert an object in between the array.

For Example ;

```
 NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 [array addObject:@"1"];
 [array addObject:@"3"];
 [array addObject:@"4"];
 [array addObject:@"5"];

 NSLog@"array is - %@", array);
```

**Output will be -**

> array is - { 1,3,4,5}

**But now i want to add another object as "2" in between this array and want the output like this ;**

> array is - { 1,2,3,4,5}

How can i do this?

I have searched but could not find the solution.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: you want to insert new object such that array looks in sorted order?

Comment: Is your question how to insert an object into the array or how to find the proper location to do the insert?

Comment: @PratyushaTerli yes exaxtly. i want to insert another object in that array

Comment: @Rohan then how about adding a new object and then sorting the array?

Comment: @PratyushaTerli not need to short an array and thanks for your reply. i got the answer :-)

Comment: If this is only your requirement then you can simply add the object into your mutable array and after that just sort this array.

Comment: If all you needed to know is about `insertObject:atIndex:`, then why didn't you first look at the docs for `NSMutableArray`? A quick scan of the docs is always what you should do first before posting a question. Plus you learn about lots of other things as you scan the docs.

Comment: @rmaddy ya you are right. And i have gone through the docs and read out for this issue, but could not find the solution so i asked question here .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[array insertObject:@"2" atIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[array addObject:@"1"];
[array addObject:@"3"];
[array addObject:@"4"];
[array addObject:@"5"];

NSLog@"array is - %@", array);
[array addObject:@"2"];
[array sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
NSLog@"array is - %@", array);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple methods to add object in an Array Like

1. If you are adding objects from array

   ```
   NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:sourceArray];
   [array addObjectsFromArray:sourceArray];
   ```
2. If you want to add only single object

   ```
   [array addObject:object];
   ```
3. If you want to add at some self defined index

   ```
   [array insertObject:object  atIndex:5];
   ```
4. If you want to add by replacing other object

   ```
   [array replaceObjectAtIndex:5 withObject:object];
   ```

   And yes we can only add or remove from array if and only if it is Mutable.

Answer (score 1):

```
[arrMutableArray insertObject:@"2" atIndex:1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Array has method name is

```
- (void)insertObjects:(NSArray *)objects atIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexes
```

Use such like

```
[myArrayName insertObject:@"My Object" atIndex:IndexNumber]; // Here put your object with number of index as you want.
```

**Description:**

> Inserts the objects in the provided array into the receiving array at the specified indexes.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *=> objects*
>   An array of objects to insert into the receiving array.
>   *=> indexes*
>   The indexes at which the objects in objects should be inserted. The count of locations in indexes must equal the count of objects. For more details, see the Discussion.
>
> **Discussion**
>   Each object in objects is inserted into the receiving array in turn at the corresponding location specified in indexes after earlier insertions have been made. The implementation is conceptually similar to that illustrated in the following example.

Above explanation take from [Apple's official documents.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/insertObject%3aatIndex%3a)

Answer (score 0):

You can use array insertobject property for that.

Just mention your objectatIndex where you want to insert.

You can try like below.

```
 [yourarray insertObject:@"Give what you want to add" atIndex:1];
```

Comment: Take NSMutablearray for that.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift

```
var someInts = [1,2,4,5]
var someVar = someInts
print(someVar)
```

O/P : `[1, 2, 4, 5]`

```
someInts.insert(3, atIndex: 2)
var append = someInts
print(append)
```

O/P : `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`